# Finding the "loser" in Each Row

Tags: r

I have this dataset ("m"):

```
structure(list(id = 1:4, A1 = c(20, 20, 20, 20), B1 = c(20, 20, 
20, 20), A2 = c(19.638362385164, 8.11972427580967, 11.9810539199604, 
11.179853022028), B2 = c(15.974094766586, 11.02249487622, 14.2062464923062, 
9.6806947619966), A3 = c(1.41008362674648, 2.36347304689385, 
5.89401239396941, 10.2478961230446), B3 = c(3.43887450489555, 
8.70503533284162, 6.31828253609099, -3.40081750462382), A4 = c(0.021848581788209, 
-0.946584014278003, -22.2024625188847, NA), B4 = c(-5.73617894284438, 
1.6375826801224, 3.8312939605301, NA)), row.names = c(1L, 5L, 
9L, 13L), class = "data.frame", reshapeWide = list(v.names = NULL, 
    timevar = "time", idvar = "id", times = 1:4, varying = structure(c("A1", 
    "B1", "A2", "B2", "A3", "B3", "A4", "B4"), .Dim = c(2L, 4L
    ))))

   id A1 B1        A2        B2        A3        B3           A4        B4
1   1 20 20 19.638362 15.974095  1.410084  3.438875   0.02184858 -5.736179
5   2 20 20  8.119724 11.022495  2.363473  8.705035  -0.94658401  1.637583
9   3 20 20 11.981054 14.206246  5.894012  6.318283 -22.20246252  3.831294
13  4 20 20 11.179853  9.680695 10.247896 -3.400818           NA        NA
```

I would like to add a column to this dataset that contains the "loser" of each row - by this I mean, whether variable "A" or variable "B" contains the lowest value. The final product would look something like this:

```
   id A1 B1        A2        B2        A3        B3           A4        B4    loser
1   1 20 20 19.638362 15.974095  1.410084  3.438875   0.02184858 -5.736179 Player B
5   2 20 20  8.119724 11.022495  2.363473  8.705035  -0.94658401  1.637583 Player A
9   3 20 20 11.981054 14.206246  5.894012  6.318283 -22.20246252  3.831294 Player A
13  4 20 20 11.179853  9.680695 10.247896 -3.400818           NA        NA Player B
```

I tried to solve this problem in an indirect way - for each row, find the column number that corresponds to the smallest element. If the column number is "odd", then loser = Player B -  else loser = Player A.

I tried to do this using the following codes:

```
 l = apply( m, 1, which.min)
 1  5  9 13 
 9  8  8  7 

    m$l = l
> ifelse(m$l %% 2 == 0,  "Player A", "Player B" )
[1] "Player B" "Player A" "Player A" "Player B"
> loser = ifelse(m$l %% 2 == 0,  "Player A", "Player B" )
> loser
[1] "Player B" "Player A" "Player A" "Player B"
> m$loser = loser
> m
   id A1 B1        A2        B2        A3        B3           A4        B4 l    loser
1   1 20 20 19.638362 15.974095  1.410084  3.438875   0.02184858 -5.736179 9 Player B
5   2 20 20  8.119724 11.022495  2.363473  8.705035  -0.94658401  1.637583 8 Player A
9   3 20 20 11.981054 14.206246  5.894012  6.318283 -22.20246252  3.831294 8 Player A
13  4 20 20 11.179853  9.680695 10.247896 -3.400818           NA        NA 7 Player B
```

- Have I done this correctly? Is my logic correct?

Thank you!

Comment: I believe you are using the function I wrote. You can modifiy it to give the looser before you reshape.

Comment: Note that at times, both players might get `-` at the same point. Who would you pick as the loser in that case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `pmap` to help pull the name of the column that has the minimum value. So, all columns are put into `c(...)` to find the minimum value, then we subset using `names`. We can then just extract only the letter and paste to "Player" to get the desired output for `loser`. You could do all of that in one step, but I decided to put it as a second `mutate` line for readability.

```
library(tidyverse)

m %>%
  mutate(loser = pmap(across(-id), ~ names(c(...)[which.min(c(...))])),
         loser = str_c("Player ", str_extract(loser, "[[:alpha:]]")))
```

**Output**

```
   id A1 B1        A2        B2        A3        B3           A4        B4    loser
1   1 20 20 19.638362 15.974095  1.410084  3.438875   0.02184858 -5.736179 Player B
5   2 20 20  8.119724 11.022495  2.363473  8.705035  -0.94658401  1.637583 Player A
9   3 20 20 11.981054 14.206246  5.894012  6.318283 -22.20246252  3.831294 Player A
13  4 20 20 11.179853  9.680695 10.247896 -3.400818           NA        NA Player B
```

Or another `tidyverse` option:

```
m %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(loser = names(.)[-1][which.min(c_across(cols = -c(id)))],
         loser = str_c("Player ", str_extract(loser, "[[:alpha:]]")))
```

Answer (score 1):

Using Base R:

```
m$loser <- sub("\\d+", '', names(m[-1])[max.col(-replace(m[-1], is.na(m[-1]),0))])

  id A1 B1        A2        B2        A3        B3           A4        B4 loser
1   1 20 20 19.638362 15.974095  1.410084  3.438875   0.02184858 -5.736179     B
5   2 20 20  8.119724 11.022495  2.363473  8.705035  -0.94658401  1.637583     A
9   3 20 20 11.981054 14.206246  5.894012  6.318283 -22.20246252  3.831294     A
13  4 20 20 11.179853  9.680695 10.247896 -3.400818           NA        NA     B
```